# Wordpress: Pages work, Posts don't

Tags: wordpress

First of all, I'm totally new to WordPress so please be patient :)

Anyway, I have created a custom theme with a bunch of pages, a menu and a startpage (index.php), and everything is working fine. I have also created a few posts and those are not working at all. I have created a small loop that display the 5 latest posts on the startpage as links with date, and they show up as intended, but if I click on one of the links the startpage just reloads. As the page has reloaded it displays the correct permalink in the browser address bar, but I'm still stuck on the startpage. Same if I try to preview my posts from WP-admin, it just display my start page.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here and I'm no php coder. This is the code I have in my page.php file, maybe there is something wrong with it?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div class="content">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); the_content(); endwhile; // THE LOOP ?>
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a difference between posts and pages. Try to put this code into a file called index.php so it will work for posts too.

If wordpress cant find a page.php (this is for pages) or single.php (this is for posts) it will look into the index.php as a fallback.

those are the files - enjoy :)
1. style.css: your page styling goes in here.
2. index.php: acts as fallback if the specific php files are not found.
3. single.php: single posts template
4. page.php: single page styling goes here
5. archive.php: acts as archives template (by month, author,...)
6. searchform.php: style and configure your searchform here
... there are many more. here is a [cheat sheet with page types / theme structure](http://cdn.tutsplus.com/wp/uploads/legacy/resources/Wordpress-Cheat-Sheet.pdf) .If you need further information google for types followed by tutorial
example: wordpress single.php tutorial

all the best
fab

Comment: Thank you Fabian, to add a single.php page was what I needed.
I asked this question about a week ago at the forum at codex.wordpress.org, and not a single answer so far. Here at Stackoverflow it took a couple of hours to get a resolving answer. Guess I'll stick to Stackoverflow solely from now on :)

And big thanks for your additional info, it'll come in handy!

Comment: You're welcome. I know that pain to deal with any other site than stackoverflow...